# How to upgrade the condenser heat of air conditioner?

Tags: heat-transfer

I am looking to utilize the heat of the condenser of an air conditioning system. Towards that end I am vacuum distilling the condenser in water at 5 kPa. The distillation will happen at around 35°C. i.e. the condenser will be rejecting heat at 35°C. Now, I want to use the steam generated in such conditions by upgrading the steam using thermocompressor or electrical compressor.

Here is a brief description of thermocompressor calculation. The steam from vacuum distillation has an enthalpy of ~2450. Now I use the thermocompressor to increase its enthalpy to ~2650 i.e. around = 90°C saturation temperature. I am using weighted average for temperature and pressure calculation. Is this economically feasible using thermocompressor? Can thermocompressor achieve an entrainment ratio of 4? I checked electrical compressor will not be so effective because it will superheat the steam thus reducing the cost benefit.

Appreciate your assistance

Comment: What pressure is needed to generate steam at 35 deg C?

Comment: Have you considered putting the air conditioner coils where you need them and skipping steam as a medium?

Comment: I think you will find that you just can't do much with steam at 35C except fight vacuum leaks.

Comment: @tiger guy. thats why i am upgrrading the  steam to have a saturation temperature of 90c. I can do a lot with it.

Comment: @AmitAgarwal, adding energy just to take it back out is always a losing proposition.

Comment: @abel the temperature of the AC coil is low.. I need to upgrade it so that it is of some use

Comment: @Tiger guy This is how a mechanical vapor compressor for simple distillation works. they compress the steam to increase its saturation temperature and then it is used for further distillation. This way the energy of the low pressure steam isn''t wasted.

Comment: @AmitAgarwal, a vapor compressor adds energy.  You can't add energy so that you can take energy out.  Because you will get less out than you put in, leaving you with less than you started with.  If this were a thing people would already be doing it.  It isn't.

Comment: @AmitAgarwal put it on a T-s diagram and you'll see how it doesn't work.